# Sum a Value Relation field in field calculator

Tags: qgis

I have a polygon layer with a Value Relation field that I'm using to capture upstream catchment areas that contribute to the selected record.

An example would be if I had 3 polygons of 100m2 - so I have 3 records in my table with a geometry area of 100m2.  But polygons A & B contribute to the catchment area of polygon C, so I use the Value Relation field to identify A & B as contributors to C.  I use the Value column to identify the polygon, but I use the Key column to save the area geometry values in the column.  I then want to add a virtual field to calculate the sum of the values in the Value Relation field and add it to the area of the particular record.  In this case, I would have a virtual field of 300m2.

The problem I'm having is summing the values of the Value Relation field (Real) - as soon as I save the table, I lose the values in the Value Relation field. Everything becomes zero.

I've been trying with the "UP_AREA" field as both a text and as a double. The text values seem to remain in the table, but the doubles are not showing up.  In the screen shot at the bottom, you can see that the AREA_ha values are being saved, but I'm not able to convert to real.

The last screenshot below shows that the values appear as expected in the UP_AREA_D field as expected when the polygon is drawn, but as soon as I save the table, the field returns to null.

Open to any and all suggestions if anyone has a better way to do this.

[image: Table fields]

[image: Value Relation settings]

[image: Table Records]

[image: Virtual Field Setings]

[image: Before Table save]

Comment: So "UP_AREA" is the value relation column? Can we see what the values look like in this column before you save the layer and they disappear?

Comment: I've updated the screenshots above, the values are staying in the table if I change the field data type to string, however, I'm not able to convert to real within my expression...

Comment: The values aren't staying because they're not the correct data type. A double type cell can't store a list of numbers.

Comment: The `sum()` function can't take a list of numbers as input. If you want to use the `sum()` function, you have to figure out an aggregate expression that does the same thing as the value relation column.